# Add score to wordpress custom post type slug

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, slug

I have the follow code for my custom post type "works", but the current code doesnt allow a score "-" on the link? What should I fix?

```
function works_rewrites_init($post_link, $post = 0){

  add_rewrite_rule('works\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)?\/([0-9]+)?(page\/)?([0-9]+)?\/?$', 'index.php?paged=$matches[4]&post_type=works&workscat=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function works_rewrites_init($post_link, $post = 0){
    $rule = 'works\/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?\/([0-9]+)?(page\/)?([0-9]+)?\/?$';
  $pageID = $post->ID;
  add_rewrite_rule($rule, 'index.php?paged=$matches[4]&post_type=works&workscat=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'works_rewrites_init');
```